# Android Lollipop Activity Screen distorted

Tags: android, android-activity, android-5.0-lollipop

I build my App with Android Lollipop SDK (21). After opening some activities and close they, one activity has this corrupted screen[image]

then i did `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` but  graphical performance is very bad. 
Is there any other solution for this problem..?

Comment: facing similar issue today.